# FFMpeg: How to add an overlay to a video; then add 5 seconds a still image + 5 seconds silence

Tags: ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg 3.2 on a linux  box.

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.10-1~deb9u1~bpo8+1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
```

I can add an overlay to the video using the following command.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y \
   -i "INPUT.MP4" \
   -i "WM.PNG" \
   -filter_complex " \
    [1:v]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.4[fg]; \
[fg]setsar=1[logo]; \
[0][logo]overlay=10:10" \
"OUTPUT.MP4"
```

This writes the output file with a transparent overlay, and preserves the original audio track.

How should I change the command - I want to have the output mp4 show a still/full-frame image -let's say for 5 seconds, added at the end of the video.

If I need to use generated audio to go with the still image, we can use silence.

If I need to specify a format for the output mp4 file, we could go with x264 video and mp3/stereo audio.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input-2min.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  Duration: 00:02:06.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2677 kb/s

    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2494 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler

    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 175 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
          handler_name    : Stereo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y \
   -i "INPUT.MP4" \
   -i "WM.PNG" \
   -loop 1 -t 5 -i "End.png" \
   -filter_complex " \
    [1:v]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.4,setsar=1[logo]; \
[0][logo]overlay=10:10[main]; \
[main][2]concat" \
   -af apad -shortest \
"OUTPUT.MP4"
```

The apad is to lengthen the audio indefinitely. The `-shortest` is to stop the file when the video stream ends.

Comment: Thanks,  that helped - i found I needed to add in a scale2ref ; I finished up with - 

`    ffmpeg -y -i "input.mp4" -i "wm.png" -loop 1 -t 5 -i "end.jpg" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.4[fg];[fg]setsar=1[logo];\
[0][logo]overlay=10:10[main];[2][main]scale2ref[ext][ref];[ref][ext]concat" -af apad -shortest "output.mp4"

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add dynamic image overlay on live stream video input? Means we can change image overlay after video stream started?